# Unexpected result while calculating the time difference in hour?

Tags: sql-server

when i am calculating the time difference by below code it shows me the difference in reverse order Why?

```
declare @startdate time = '08:00:00', @enddate time = '01:00:00'
declare @hour varchar(25),@minutes varchar(25),@seconds varchar(25)

set @hour=datediff(ss,@startdate,@enddate)/60/60%12
set @minutes= datediff(ss,@startdate,@enddate)/60%60 
set @seconds= datediff(ss,@startdate,@enddate)%60

select @hour+':'+@minutes+':'+@seconds
```

I am calculating the difference on 12 hour. I am expecting the difference is 5 hours. but it showing me -7 hours. can somebody explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the sql server takes the 24 hour format.
You can specify if it is A.M or P.M.

```
declare @startdate time = '08:00:00 AM', @enddate time = '01:00:00 PM'
SELECT DATEDIFF(HH,@startdate,@enddate)
```

This works, if the time specified does not involve two different dates, unless mentioned.
Ex:

```
declare @startdate time = '08:00:00 PM', @enddate time = '01:00:00 PM'
    SELECT DATEDIFF(HH,@startdate,@enddate)
```

This will result in a wrong value as the `@enddate` falls on the next date.
To obtain better results, it is advisable to specify dates along with the time.

```
select datediff(HH, '02-21-2017 08:00:00 pm'  ,'02-22-2017 01:00:00 PM')
```

Answer (score 2):

That output is exactly correct. 01:00 is 7 hours behind 08:00. That's why you get a negative number.

You said you're calculating the difference using a 12 hour clock. Ok, then you need to indicate that to SQL Server somehow. Either use `13:00` as the end time or parse the date with the `AM` or `PM` meridian indicator in the time string.

I **highly** recommend you only deal with time in 24 hour. It will spare you many headaches and make you code much easier to understand. Save time presentation and parsing for the UI layer.

Comment: thanks for clarification but now i am taking startdate='08:00:00 pm' and enddate='01:00:00 pm' but still stuck with the same result i.e. -7 and the output should be like 17 hours because the time start from night 8 o'clock to afternoon 1 o'clock. why ? using both 12 and 24 clock

Comment: Try passing the date along with the time. It should yield your desired result.